# Trouble writing standard deviation Java Code

Tags: java

The title is pretty self explanatory of my issue.

I am trying to write a program which will calculate the standard deviation of a set of numbers input by the user.
This was a lot tougher than I had anticipated and writing the algorithm for it has been a pain.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StandardDeviation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double num;
        double total;
        int n;

        System.out.print("First Number: ");
        num = input.nextDouble();

        n = 0;
        total = 0;

        while ( num != -1 ) {

            n++;
            total += num;
            System.out.print("Next Number: ");
            num = input.nextDouble();
        }

        double mean;
        double dev;
        double devn;
        double sqrt;

        mean = total/n;
        dev = (total - mean);
        devn = dev/n;
        sqrt = Math.sqrt(devn);

        System.out.println("N= " +n);
        System.out.println("Total= " +total);
        System.out.println("Mean= " +mean);
        System.out.println("Deviation= " +dev);

        System.out.print("The standard deviation is: " +sqrt);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting a compile error? Is the output unexpected?

Comment: Output is incorrect, I am testing the numbers 13,24,25,12

Comment: check the formula for standard deviation. You are subtracting mean from total. What you really should be doing is subtract each input from mean, square the result and finally sum them to get sum of square of deviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your algorithm is wrong. You cannot compute standard deviation by accumulating your samples alone. You must also accumulate their squares.

Like this:

```
    n = 0;
    total = 0;
    total_squared = 0;

    while ( num != -1 ) {

        n++;
        total += num;
        total_squared += num*num;
        System.out.print("Next Number: ");
        num = input.nextDouble();
    }
```

Your solution will be:

```
    mean = total/n;
    stddev = sqrt(total_squared/n - mean*mean);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes so much sense and much simpler than I had it written!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you calculate standard deviation with some sample data.

```
double[] a = {10, 20, 30};
double total = 0;

for (double i : a) {
    total += i;
}

double mean = total/a.length;

double sqTot = 0;
for (double i : a) {
    sqTot += Math.pow((i-mean), 2);
}

System.out.println("Standard deviation " + Math.sqrt(sqTot/a.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula for standard deviation is wrong. This will do:

```
n = 0;
total = 0;
total_sq = 0;

while ( num != -1 ) {
    n++;
    total += num;
    total_sq += num*num;
    System.out.print("Next Number: ");
    num = input.nextDouble();
}
```

For population standard deviation:

```
mean = total/n;
dev_p = sqrt(total_sq/n - mean*mean);
```

For sample standard deviatiod:

```
dev_s = dev_p * n/(n-1);
```